# magento 1.x admin reports are stored in which table?

Tags: admin, magento-1, reports

Magento admin generated reports are stored in which table.

https://prnt.sc/g5dr84

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables are `sales_order_aggregated_created` and `sales_order_aggregated_updated` depending on what you choose for the filter "Match period to".